# Svn Checkout Large number of files in single folder

Tags: svn, svn-checkout

Need help on SVN checkout have 30K+ Audio files are there in single folder.
While checking out through CLI or GUI (Using win7), its giving error after ~900 files (Approx. 1.5GB).
Need solution to checkout all files.
I can't checkout in different folder in chunk, because i need to do some changes with those audio file and push it again.

Need your suggestion.

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: svn: E175012: Connection timed out

Comment: BTW,  to maintain such amount of binary files via SVN may not be a good idea.  Log files will became very large if the files changes frequently.

Comment: It can be an SVN configuration to kill connection after some time. Or the service you are using to upload your files maybe killing the connection. You should investigate this.

Comment: Are you using Apache, svnserve, or svn+ssh to access the repository?